# electron BrowserWindow doesn't hide

Tags: electron

I tried many things, read different threads ... but didn't get an answer.

I've got a very simple electron app ...

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
const path = require('path');

let playerWindow

app.whenReady().then(() => {

    playerWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        kiosk: true,
        backgroundColor: '#000',
        webPreferences: {
            preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
        }
    })

    playerWindow.webContents.openDevTools()

    playerWindow.loadFile('src/managerWindows/index.html').then( () => {
        console.log('HELLO')
        console.log(playerWindow)
        playerWindow.hide()
    })
})

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    app.quit()
})
```

It works so far. It logs out the information fine, including playerWindows functions

```
HELLO
BrowserWindow {
  setBounds: [Function (anonymous)],
  _events: [Object: null prototype] {
    blur: [Function (anonymous)],
    focus: [Function (anonymous)],
    show: [Function: visibilityChanged],
    hide: [Function: visibilityChanged],
    minimize: [Function: visibilityChanged],
    maximize: [Function: visibilityChanged],
    restore: [Function: visibilityChanged]
  },
  _eventsCount: 7,
  devToolsWebContents: [Getter]
}
```

BUT `playerWindow.hide()` doesn't work. The window is still visible.

Why?

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Have you try placing the `playerWindow.hide()` line **after** the closing brackets of the `playerWindow.loadFile(...).then(...)` statement?

Comment: Yes, I did. But as you can see in my answer it was another "problem". Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
// ...
playerWindow.loadFile('src/managerWindows/index.html');

playerWindow.webContents.on('did-finish-load', function() {
    playerWindow.hide()
});
```

`did-finish-load` is an event emitted when `loadURL` or `loadFile` are fully loaded. There are also events to manage load errors and similar.

Reference: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/web-contents#event-did-finish-load